# Symfony/ Mamp/ Mac/ DebugClassLoader

Tags: php, macos, symfony, mamp

I am working on a website that as been created with Symfony on a Windows operating system. I have downloaded the folder on my Mac Yosemite using MAMP.

I can see the **"config.php" page**:

```
Welcome!

Welcome to your new Symfony project.

This script will guide you through the basic configuration of your project.    
You can also do the same by editing the ‘app/config/parameters.yml’ file directly.

Your configuration looks good to run Symfony.

Configure your Symfony Application online
Bypass configuration and go to the Welcome page
Symfony Standard Edition.
```

---

But when I click on the "**BypassConfiguration**" an error message appear:

> FatalErrorException: Compile Error:
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader::loadClass(): Failed opening
>   required
>   '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/WebsiteDigital/Website/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOSUserBundle.php'
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.6/lib/php') in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/WebsiteDigital/Website/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php
>   line 154

---

Here is a copy of the **DebugClassLoader.php** line 154 as it mention on the error msg :

```
 **
 * Loads the given class or interface.
 *
 * @param string $class The name of the class
 *
 * @return bool|null    True, if loaded
 *
 * @throws \RuntimeException
 */
public function loadClass($class)
{
    ErrorHandler::stackErrors();

    try {
        if ($this->isFinder) {
            if ($file = $this->classLoader[0]->findFile($class)) {
                require $file;
            }
        } else {
            call_user_func($this->classLoader, $class);
            $file = false;
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        ErrorHandler::unstackErrors();

        throw $e;
    }

    ErrorHandler::unstackErrors();
```

---

Does it mean something for somebody?
I can send you more information If it's needed.

Comment: if you search in `phpinfo();` is xdebug enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You got an error message with the following content:

**Failed opening required ... vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOSUserBundle.php**

A vendor file is missing.

Your application is not properly installed.

Did you follow all installation steps?

Did you fetch all dependencies (packages/bundles) via `composer install`?

Fetch all dependencies with Composer, then try again.